# Can this glob clause in SQLite be replaced?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, glob

So, I understand that a clause like `(x GLOB 'abc*')` can be replaced by `(x >= 'abc' AND x < 'abd')` but I'm using a clause that looks like this `(x GLOB '*abc*')` and it's an expensive operation. Is there any way I can replace it in the same way the first expression was replaced?

Comment: No, it can't be simplified, because you need to search everywhere in the string.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I suspected. I just felt like there might be a faster, but slightly less accurate way. Thanks for confirming this though. Do you know of anything faster than a glob that does the same thing? I assume this is the fastest it will get.

Comment: See the SQLite Full Text Search extension.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, that helps a lot! If you submit an answer to this question, I'll mark it correct!

Comment: I don't have an answer to submit. Just google it to find out more info.

Comment: @Barmar I meant an answer that contains what you've written in these comments, I will look into Full Text Search as it does seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to simplify searching for strings in the middle of a column, other than using a full-text indexes.

Comment: FTS does not allow searching in the middle of words.